# How to stop JavaScript from periodically refreshing web page content on the server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, getelementbyid

In the process of learning some JavaScript, I've managed to assemble examples that help me periodically (every 3 seconds, in this example) refresh the content of my web page, and take a specific action (refresh the page) after one of the dynamic tags is populated with a specific string.

What I cannot seem to figure out is how to stop the dynamic content from being polled once a tag () I'm evaluating matches a specific condition.

Here is what I have in place, which is generally working for me:

Say for example I have a web page that contains dynamic elements assigned the  id tags of "leftHealth", "leftEnergy", "rightEnergy", and "turnMsg":

```
// On page load, instantiate a listener and begin polling the server for content.
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var xhr = null;

    function getXmlHttpRequestObject(){
        if(!xhr){               
            // Create a new XMLHttpRequest object 
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        return xhr;
    }

    function updateLiveData(){
        var now = new Date();
        // Date string is appended as a query with live data to avoid caching issues
        var url = 'updatedVals.php?ID=' + ID + '&userName=' + userName + '&time=' + now.getTime();
        xhr = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = eventHandler;
        // asynchronous requests
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        // Send the request over the network
        xhr.send(null);
    }

    updateLiveData();


    function eventHandler(){
        // Check response is ready or not
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            ['leftHealth','leftEnergy','rightEnergy','turnMsg'].forEach(function(i){
                 document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = data[i]
            });
        setTimeout(updateLiveData, 3000); // Update the live data every 3 sec
        }
    }
});
```

And here I watch for one of the tags matching a certain value and, when that happens, wait ~4 seconds then refresh the page:

```
// Start listening for changes in the root HTML element of the page.
mutationObserver.observe(document.documentElement, {
  attributes: true,
  characterData: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributeOldValue: true,
  characterDataOldValue: true
});

var counter = 0;
var i = setInterval(function(){
    // Evaluate the "turnMsg" document element we're evaluating and check for the string "Stunned".
    // But even if it does not show up, refresh the page about every minute or so.
    let s = document.getElementById('turnMsg').innerHTML;
    let result = s.includes("Stunned");
    counter++;
    // If <div id="turnMsg"> contains "Stunned", wait 4 seconds then refresh.
    if ((result) || (counter == 15)){
        if (result){
            var i = setInterval(function(){
            }, 4000);
        }
        clearInterval(i);
        mutationObserver.disconnect();  // Stop the MutationObserver from listening for changes.
        location.reload(); // Reload the page.
    }
}, 3000);
```

This is all working reasonably well (perhaps given how sketchy my JavaScript knowledge is!). But what I cannot quite figure out how to do is STOP the process of polling the server (sending that XmlHttpRequest) every 3 seconds and updating content of the page once one of the content refresh polls pulls back the condition that the value going into  is less than zero. When the value returned in document.getElementById('leftHealth').innerHTML < 0, I no longer need the web page's content to refresh -- that's just wasting bandwidth and DB queries in the target php page because values returned from thes server will no longer change.

Comment: Use `clearInterval(i)` to stop the interval function when a condition is met.

Comment: My efforts have been focused on attaching a conditional (if stmt) to the execution of the line of code, " setTimeout(updateLiveData, 3000);" as the place this process should be interrupted, but either that's wrong, or I'm not evaluating the value of document.getElementById('leftHealth').innerHTML properly... but it sounds like you're saying I need to do that AND then clear the interval if my conditional evaluates to true? Or are you saying change from using setTimeout in the upper code example to setInterval in that upper block of code (and, if so, why?)  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I just noticed that you already have `clearInterval(i)` in the code. That should stop it from polling every 3 seconds.

Comment: Although you don't really need to do that when you call `location.reload()` since that kills everything that's running in the page.

Comment: The `i` in that `clearInterval()` is not the same as the global variable. You're clearing the inner 4-second interval timer that doesn't do anything, not the outer 3-second timer. Please don't use the same variable name like this, it creates confusion.

Comment: And you're not actually waiting 4 seconds. You start an interval timer, then immediately clear it. If you want to wait 4 seconds for something, use `setTimeout()` and put the code that should wait inside the callback function.

Comment: Thank you.  I fear I've included too much information in my initial sample. That pause before the refresh isn't the problem I'm asking about. It's the recurring 3-second content refresh in the FIRST block of code that refreshes the web page's dynamic content.

THAT content refresh is governed by the "setTimeout(updateLiveData, 3000);" line. 

Re-stated, the problem is how can I parse the value of document.getElementById('leftHealth').innerHTML to check if that JSON value is < 0 and, if so, stop the looping xmlHttpRequests, that poll the target php page?

Thanks for your help and patience

Comment: Didn't my answer explain how to stop the 3-second interval timer?

Comment: I'm sorry, but no; it addressed the wrong recurring timer. I'm trying to stop the timer occurring with the call to the updateLiveData function based on a condition being met.  This is what I've tried, but cannot understand why it's not working:
```
if ((document.getElementById("leftHealth").innerHTML > 0) && (document.getElementById("leftEnergy").innerHTML > 0)){
        setTimeout(updateLiveData, 3000); // Update the live data every 3 sec
}
```
It seems to me, that would stop the recurring calling on updateLiveData that occurs when the ready state changes.

Comment: Occurring with the what?

Comment: There are only two interval timers in your code, the 3-second timer that checks for `stunned`, and the 4-second timer that does nothing. My code shows how to stop the 3-second timer, and I replaced the 4-second interval with a 4-second delay.

Comment: I'm sorry -- I understand your confusion and it's my fault. I'm calling the polling for data that occurs on readystatechange, which happens every 3 seconds as a "timer," which is sloppy wording on my part.

Comment: Why don't you use `setInterval()` for that one as well, instead of calling `setTimeout()` in the callback function? Then you can use `clearInterval()` to stop it.

Comment: The alternative is to put code in`updateLiveData()` that checks the condition, and doesn't call `setTimeout()` if the condition to stop is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your condition to stop matches, call `clearInterval()` on the 3-second interval timer.

Then use `setTimeout()` to reload the page 4 seconds later.

```js
var counter = 0;
var three_second_timer = setInterval(function() {
  // Evaluate the "turnMsg" document element we're evaluating and check for the string "Stunned".
  // But even if it does not show up, refresh the page about every minute or so.
  let s = document.getElementById('turnMsg').innerHTML;
  // If <div id="turnMsg"> contains "Stunned", wait 4 seconds then refresh.
  if ( s.includes("Stunned") || (++counter == 15)) {
    clearInterval(three_second_timer);
    mutationObserver.disconnect(); // Stop the MutationObserver from listening for changes.
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Reload the page.
      location.reload();
    }, 4000);
  }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. While this didn't solve the problem I originally asked about, it did fix a problem in the code example I included, making that code block work correctly and your suggestions put me on the path toward solving the issue I was stumped by.